# how to add the url of a local image in your gallery to tailwind css in order to create a background image?

Tags: url, tailwind-css, background-image

when i put url('.\images\desktop\image.jpg') in the background-image class, it dont work. i dont know if there is something im not doing right

as mentioned earlier, i tried that yet its not working

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried doing it like this? It's working on the tailwind playground

```html
<div class="h-screen w-screen bg-[url(http://cdn.backgroundhost.com/backgrounds/subtlepatterns/45degreee_fabric.png)]">Hello World</div>
```

Paylground link: https://play.tailwindcss.com/d7p8F9q7X6

More info in the documentation https://tailwindcss.com/docs/background-image#arbitrary-values

Hope that helps